# Center IMG (within an a tag) on page in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

The 'clickable' region of the `<a>` gets expanded across the full width of the containing div (or the body when not within a div) in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.

How do I make it so that the img is centered and only the image is 'clickable' as per the behavior of IE?

html

```
<a href='http://www.google.com'>
  <img src='http://cecs.anu.edu.au/files/GoogleLogo.png' />
</a>
```

css

```
img {
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapp it by div

```
<div class="container">
    <a href='http://www.google.com'>
        <img src='http://cecs.anu.edu.au/files/GoogleLogo.png' />
    </a>
<div>
```

and style

```
img {
    height:100px;
    display:block;
}
div.container{
    width:300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmwz9/AxtLH/)

Answer (score 1):

**define this**

```
a{display:block;text-align:center;}
```

Comment: no this does not work, the img becomes left aligned and the clickable area is still full width